# Using python to input text to a different window

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a python 3 program that types something in another window, such as Google Chrome.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you mean as a form or in the search bar?

Comment: Everything is possible

Comment: If you are specifically talking about Websites you can use selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little open ended, but it sounds like you want an http server. You can use either [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) or make your own from scratch. A basic HelloWorld for using python3's http module is [here](https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2015/06/03/create-a-simple-http-server-with-python-3/). I used [this simple guide](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/) to help me understand the basics of web servers in python. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

searchbar = (x, y)
text_or_url = "hello word!"

pyautogui.click(searchbar)
pyautogui.typewrite(text_or_url)
pyautogui.typewrite([Enter])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pywinauto lib

It is very easy.

For example you have opened notepad window and opened 'Save as' dialog and want to type filename:

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.connect(title='test1.txt - Notepad')
app.SaveAs.Edit1.type_keys("C:\\test2.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pywinauto lib

```
filePath.set_text('D:\\aa.txt') 
inpuMsg.type_keys('D:\\aa.txt')
```

[set_text](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.html?highlight=set_text#pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.EditWrapper.set_text)

[type_keys](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html?highlight=type_keys#pywinauto.base_wrapper.BaseWrapper.type_keys)